# My php function is not able to change it´s class variable value

Tags: php, function, object, variables

So I have this problem: I have function called `admin_connected(boolean)` and in the code I put true or false into this boolean whether username and password are correct or not. This function is a class called Driver and what I want to happen is that when the function is triggered it saves the boolean value into a Driver´s variable so I can work with the value later. What happens is it doesn´t save the value at all.

```
class Driver
{
    public $is_admin_connected_q;

    public function admin_connected($admin_connected)
    {
        $this->is_admin_connected_q = $admin_connected; // Does not save the value
    }

    public function return_is_admin_connected() // Function used to tell the program whether it should 
                                                // render standard UI or administrator´s UI
    {
        return($this->is_admin_connected_q;);
    }

}
```

I am 100% sure the problem is in saving the boolean value in `$this->is_admin_connected_q` because if I write

```
   public function admin_connected($admin_connected)
    {
        $this->is_admin_connected_q = true;
    }
```

changing the value of `$admin_connected` manually to true it doesn´t work. However if I write that

```
public $is_admin_connected_q = true;
```

it works perfectly. The problem isn´t in refreshing the page because it doesn´t even work immediately after signing up sa administraitor.

Do you guys have any clues how to solve this problem. I´ll be welcoming any help.

Comment: In the line: return($is_admin_connected_q;);
should the first semicolon be there?

Comment: It should be `return $this->is_admin_connected_q;`. How exactly are you calling the methods? How are you verifying there is actually a problem?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath no, OP is not missing a `$` in their setter. See https://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.properties.php#language.oop5.properties

Comment: @Phil, sorry I have it in the actual not working code, I fixed it on this page now

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath No, that is not correct syntax

Comment: In all likelihood, `admin_connected()` never gets called, because you're probably calling the method _before_ redirect, and that value doesn't get retained after that; you may want to consider sessions instead ...

Answer (score 1):

This problem is inside `return_is_admin_connected()` function. Change it as follows:

```php
public function return_is_admin_connected()
{
    return $this->is_admin_connected_q;
}
```

Comment: I tried to change it but it still does not work properly.

Comment: What do you mean "save"? Setting a property and getting it just works in runtime and if you want to save and use it later for a user,you should save it inside your database as a record and when user logged out change it to false.

Comment: That´s actually a great idea I´m gonna try it!

Comment: Ok! But the main question is that why you are trying to do that? Why you need to have it? The best way is to set a session for loged in user and check the session for user. Also you can set an expire time for your session and force user to log in again when session expired and delete session if user loged out. Search for "Authentication in PHP" in Google and read some articles.